Error in my sequence convergence epsilon proof?
I have followed an example showing that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{n+1}{n})=1$ using an epsilon proof. I have attempted for my understanding to approach a proof of contradiction to show the same limit $\not= 0$. If someone could please identify for me the error in my logic it would greatly help with my understanding. My approach is as follows:
Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{n+1}{n})\not=0$.
First, assume the contrary; that is, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{n+1}{n})=0$.
To determine a suitable N, first note that $| \frac{n+1}{n} - 0| < \epsilon$.
Evaluating the LHS: $| \frac{n+1}{n} - 0| = |\frac{n+1}{n}| = |1 + \frac{1}{n}| \leq |1| + |\frac{1}{n}|$ (by the triangle inequality), $ = 1 + \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$, so $n > \frac{1}{\epsilon - 1}$.
Take $N > \frac{1}{\epsilon - 1}$. Then for $n \geq N$,
$|\frac{n+1}{n}| \leq 1 + \frac{1}{n} < 1+\frac{1}{N} < 1 + \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\epsilon - 1}} = 1 + \epsilon - 1 = \epsilon$, seemingly proving the limit $= 0$.
Thank you in advance for your time. Additionally, if anyone notices any issues with how I structure/write my proofs, I'd greatly appreciate feedback.

What if $\varepsilon < 1$ ?

When you got $1+\frac 1n < \epsilon$ you have pretty much finished your proof.  Your assumption was this would work for ALL $\epsilon>0$ any you have proven that in only works for $\epsilon > 1$.  ... and notice that for any $\epsilon > 1$ then there is an $N$ where $n>N$ implies $1< |\frac {n+1}{n}-0| < \epsilon$ and there is no contradiction in that (there's no benefit and use in it, but no contradiction.


Evaluating the LHS: $|\frac{n+1}n−0|=|\frac{n+1}n|=|1+\frac 1n|≤|1|+|\frac 1n|$ (by the triangle inequality), $=1+\frac1n <ϵ$, so ...

That's actually the contradiction you were seeking.
You are assuming that for ALL $\epsilon > 0$ that we can do our proof.  But you have proven that if $|\frac {n+1}n -0| < \epsilon$ then $\epsilon >1+\frac 1n > 1$.  So you have proven that $|\frac {n+1}n -0|$ will NEVER be less than any $\epsilon$ unless that $\epsilon > 1$.
And not every positive $\epsilon$ is less than $1$.
Thus you've reach a contradiction and your proof is done.
....
Of course, it might have been easier to note that as $\frac {n+1}n = 1 + \frac 1n > 1$ we can not have the limit be anything less than $1$.

Thank you for your response, I really appreciate the insight

I would advise you try to stick closer to the structure of the definition to avoid confusions like this. If a sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to $0$, it would mean

For every $\varepsilon>0$, there is $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $|a_n|<\varepsilon$ for all $n\ge N$.

In your case, given $\varepsilon>0$, you seek a $N$ such that $$|a_n|=1+\frac1n<\varepsilon$$
But there is a issue already: the LHS is always $\geq1$, so if you take, say $\varepsilon=1/2$, then no $n$ satisfies $|a_n|<\varepsilon$, so the sequence cannot converge to $0$.
Try seeing how all this works out if you try to prove the convergence to $1$.
Hope this helps. :)

Thank you for your reply, that's super helpful advice!


First, assume the contrary; that is, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{n+1}{n})=0$.
To determine a suitable N, first note that $| \frac{n+1}{n} - 0| < \epsilon$.

This is not how it should be said. If you are assuming that the limit is zero, then what you know is that if you prescribe some $\def\e{\epsilon}\e>0$ then there exists $N$ such that $|\frac{n+1}n|<\e$ for all $n>N$.

Evaluating the LHS: $| \frac{n+1}{n} - 0| = |\frac{n+1}{n}| = |1 + \frac{1}{n}| \leq |1| + |\frac{1}{n}|$ (by the triangle inequality), $ = 1 + \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$, so $n > \frac{1}{\epsilon - 1}$.

Besides the fact that your argument never says where $\e$ is coming from, you cannot reason as you did. Even if you know that $|x|<\e$, then getting that $|x|<2$ does not allow you to say that $2<\e$ (maybe $\e=0.3$). As mentioned in the comments, the inequality you wrote forces $\e>1$, and there is no reason for that to be true.

Take $N > \frac{1}{\epsilon - 1}$. Then for $n \geq N$,
$|\frac{n+1}{n}| \leq 1 + \frac{1}{n} < 1+\frac{1}{N} < 1 + \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\epsilon - 1}} = 1 + \epsilon - 1 = \epsilon$, seemingly proving the limit $= 0$.

This wouldn't show that the limit is zero (nor that it exists) as you forced $\e>1$, which is very much against the spirit of "epsilon" proofs, where you want to allow $\e$ to be arbitrarily close to zero.
In any case, besides the mistakes, your argument is leading you nowhere, as you assumed that the limit is zero, and you then argued that the limit is zero.

While I'm not sure this is a useful exercise in order to understand limits, here is how I would do it. First, by contradiction (just to follow your lead, but this approach is a waste of time).

Suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}n=0$. Then for any $\e>0$ there exists $N$ such that $\frac{n+1}n<\e$ for all $n>N$. In particular, taking $\e=1$, for any $n>N$
$$
>1>\frac{n+1}n=1+\frac1n>1,
$$
a contradiction.

The reason why the above is a waste of time is that one can simply say that for any $n\in\mathbb N$ we have
$$
\frac{n+1}n=1+\frac1n>1.
$$
So the limit will necessarily be at least $1$.

Thank you for your response Martin, these notes are really helpful and make the exercise make much more sense

Ultralegend and others correctly point out various issues with the proof.
More directly, there is also another significant error in your proof, I believe only partially addressed by previous answers.
When going from $1 + \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$ to $n > \frac{1}{\epsilon - 1}$, you've assumed $\epsilon -1 > 0$.  For pretty much any analysis proof, we really only care about epsilon arbitrarily close to zero.  It is possible to modify the proof attempt, by requiring $$0 < \epsilon < 1.$$ This makes $$\epsilon -1 < 0.$$  Then when dividing by $\epsilon -1 < 0$ we must flip the inequality, both sides to solve for n, we get $$ n<\frac{1}{\epsilon -1}$$
It may possible to play around with it and get $n>f(\epsilon)$, but likely not ultimately very fruitful.
To disprove a limit, I usually prove the following
For an $\epsilon > 0$ and for any choice of N>0, there exists an $n>N$ which $|f(n)-L| > \epsilon$
In your case, take $\epsilon >\frac12$, and OP can work out the rest.
The moral of the story is- be careful multiplying or dividing an inequality by variable expressions.  Sometimes this requires two cases which can create complications.
